# Auto connect to debug mode in Galaxy Tab

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, testing

Sir,

when I change some code and test my App by pressing run or Ctrl + F11 , it always displays the opo up message for Application is going to debug . HOw to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because CTRL+f11 is for debug the application. To run the application right click on the project and click on "Run As" and click on "Run configurations". Then Browse the project and press on "Target" tab and select "Always prompt to pick device" . Press "Apply" and then "Run".

Now whenever you run it will ask you to pick device on which device you want to run application. Then select your galaxy tab.

Hope it help!!

Comment: It still occurs whenever there are changes in coding

Comment: Every time you have to run -> right click on project-> Run as-> Android Application and Pick the device. Never press CTRL+f11 .